# Network connectivity weirdness (local net but no internet)

Tags: internet, networking

Here is my situation: I have a computer (A Dell) with a Broadcom ethernet card and an Intel Wireless card. The wireless card is disabled, the Broadcom enabled. The broadcom card has a dedicated IP address (and it needs to be that way) and dedicated DNS server addresses (again, it has to be that way). Using IE or FireFox, I can connect to the local machine "next" to it and tap all the exposed resources, etc.

For reasons I won't go into here, the network includes two Wireless Access Points set up to speak only to each other. This computer is on the "north" side of the network, the cable modem and router that connect to "the world" are on the "south" side of the wireless bridge. The other computers on the "north" side of the connection work just fine - connect to each other, connect to the internet - no problem, just this one computer does not. The one in question can, as I said, see the other computers on the "north" side of the wireless bridge, and it can even connect to the "north" end of the bridge itself - meaning that I can see the WAP configuration screen.

Using another computer, I can connect to the "south" side and see it's corresponding WAP setup screen - no problem. However, the computer in question CANNOT connect to the "southern" WAP device and cannot connect to the internet. Both WAP devices are LinkSys WAP 2.6. Even worse, the computer in question is host for multiple VMWare sessions, all of which CAN connect just fine. It's JUST THE HOST computer that cannot connect to the internet. So... where is the configuration screwed up?

I'm a software engineer, not a hardware guy and I'll freely admit my ignorance. If someone could kindly help me out, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If south and north are different IP networks, check routing table first.
Than install wireshark on computer in question (or tshark if it is unix with shall only), one computer in north segment and one in south segment. 
Start monitoring network traffic and try connect to computer on north segment, save log. Monitor connection to south segment, save log. Monitor connection to internet, save log.
Usually these things could happen:
1. you cannot see any outgoing packed - usually firewall related on local computer, check firewall
2. if packed goes out of problematic computer, you can see also arp request to destination IP if you see it also for IP from remote network, it is problem with routing table, if packet is routed correctly and still is not possible to deliver it, you should see ICMP packed with error explanation (in oposite direction) for example "host unreachable".
3. When you will compare traffic on source computer and destination one in south segment
and you will see differencies, something disappeared in the middle. Check switches and wireless access points. If you has such possibility, than remove as much as possible devices between source and destination computer or change each device one by one and compare results.